# Make Element Appear After Another Element Using Only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<h2 class="brand> </h2>
..
.. (lots of other elements like <img, p, h2 etc) 
..

<div class="reviews">...</div>
```

How can I use CSS to make the div element with class "reviews" appear after the h2 element with the class "brand". Something like this:

```
<h2 class="brand> </h2>
<div class="reviews">...</div>
..
.. (lots of other elements like <img, p, h2 etc) 
..
```

UPDATE: I was able to set the margin-top to negative to make it appear where I wanted but now it looks like it is floating on top of things. I used display:block but still it seems floating on top of things. I want it to occupy space.

The negative margin does not appear correctly since different screen sizes will have different negative margins and they are displaying at different positions.

Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Not that I know of.. jQuery would be perfect for something like this.

Comment: You can't rearrange the dom with CSS even if you could you shouldn't

Comment: "Moving" in the sense of DOM manipulation is not possible using CSS. If you mean that `<div class="reviews">` would *appear* after `<h2 class="brand">` that is a different story.

Comment: The best thing you can do with CSS is make it "appear" in the desired position.  But you cannot change the DOM with CSS.

Comment: Yes, I want it to appear after the brand element not changing the DOM structure. I will update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flexbox. It introduces the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property which allows you to reorder flex items:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;          /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: column; /* Column layout */
}
#wrapper > .brand ~ :not(.reviews) {
  order: 1;               /* Move to the bottom */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2 class="brand">Title</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div>Div</div>
  <div class="reviews">Reviews</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can play a bit with `display: table-*` CSS properties: if all elements are wrapped in a common container (e.g. a `main` element)

```
<main>
  <h2 class="brand">Title</h2>

   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   <p>lorem ipsum</p>

   <div class="reviews">reviews</div>
</main>
```

You can move up the `.reviews` element like so

```
main          { display: table; }   
main .brand   { display: table-caption; }
main .reviews { display: table-header-group; }
```

**Codepen** : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbEBma

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Even though you can, you shouldn't.

Comment: why not @Chrillewoodz ? Those properties are well supported since `IE8`

Comment: Because there are better ways of making things appear where they should, without using hacky solutions, as I would classify this one as. Even though it's a cool solution, don't get me wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole arrangement of items is not contained in the table. It is a very complicated structure of elements.

Comment: I should point out that is requirement is because we are implementing responsive design where reviews are shown somewhere else on mobile as compared to the desktop version.

Comment: @JohnDoe: there's no table elements in my example... this can be perfectly responsive